# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong or why it gives me the output it does, I'll copy& paste my code for the two classes and the console output I get and maybe someone better than me at Java can help figure this out, I'm certain it's something trivial:
**first class**

```
public class PoolTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Pool newPool = new Pool();
        System.out.println(newPool.getValue('q'));
        System.out.println(newPool.getTiles(10));
        newPool.poolReset();
        System.out.println(newPool.getTiles(11));
        /* We have 100 tiles in the pool */
        System.out.println(newPool.getTilesRemaining()); //100
        System.out.println(newPool.isEmpty()); //false
        newPool.getTiles(5); //ok
        System.out.println(newPool.getTilesRemaining()); //95
    }
}
```

**second class**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Pool {
char[] zeroPoint = {'*','*'};
char[] onePoint = {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','n','n','n','n','n','n','r','r','r','r','r','r','t','t','t','t','t','t','l','l','l','l','s','s','s','s','u','u','u','u'};
char[] twoPoint = {'d','d','d','d', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g',};
char[] threePoint = {'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'm', 'm', 'p', 'p'};
char[] fourPoint = {'f', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y'};
char[] fivePoint = {'k'};
char[] eightPoint = {'j', 'x'};
char[] tenPoint = {'q', 'z'};
char[] charPool = new char[102];
String stringPool = new String(onePoint)+ new String(twoPoint)+ new String(threePoint)+ new String(fourPoint)+ new String(fivePoint)+ new String(eightPoint)+ new String(tenPoint);
public Pool(){
    charPool = stringPool.toCharArray();
}

public int getValue(char letter){
    int value=0;
    if(new String(zeroPoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=0;
    } else if(new String(onePoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=1;
    } else if(new String(twoPoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=2;
    } else if(new String(threePoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=3;
    } else if(new String(fourPoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=4;
    } else if(new String(fivePoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=5;
    } else if(new String(eightPoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=8;
    } else if(new String(tenPoint).indexOf(letter)>-1){
        value=10;
    }

    return value;
}

public void poolReset(){
    charPool = stringPool.toCharArray();
}

public char[] getTiles(int numberOfTiles){
    Random randomTile = new Random();
    int randomNum;
    int returned;
    char[] tilesReturned = new char[numberOfTiles];

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfTiles; i++){
        returned=0;
        do{
            randomNum=randomTile.nextInt(102);
            if(charPool[randomNum]!='0') {
                tilesReturned[i]=charPool[randomNum];
                charPool[randomNum]='0';
                returned = 1;
            }
        }while(returned==0);
    }
    return tilesReturned;
}
public char[] swapTiles(char[] tilesToSwap){
    Random randomTile = new Random();
    int randomNum;
    int returned;
    int numberOfTiles = tilesToSwap.length;
    char[] tilesReturned = new char[numberOfTiles];

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfTiles; i++){
        returned=0;
        while(returned==0){
            randomNum=randomTile.nextInt(102);
            if(charPool[randomNum]!='0') {
                tilesReturned[i]=charPool[randomNum];
                charPool[randomNum]=tilesToSwap[randomNum];
                returned = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return tilesReturned;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    boolean empty=true;
    for(int i=0; i<102; i++){
        if(charPool[i]!='0'){
            empty=false;
        }
    }
    return empty;
}

public int getTilesRemaining(){
    int tilesRemaining=0;
    for(int i=0; i<102; i++){
        if(charPool[i]=='0'){
            tilesRemaining++;
        }
    }
    return tilesRemaining;
}

}
```

**console output**

```
10
stsfrebias
goresthltii
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 99
    at Pool.getTilesRemaining(Pool.java:98)
    at PoolTest.main(PoolTest.java:10)
```

Comment: Debugger is your friend!

Comment: In Java, arrays have a length property, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Seems like you just in some 'for' cycle have mistake with index range. Do not be lazy - use debugger and check it. :)

Comment: At which point is line 98?

Comment: everything is there, charPool contains 98 characters, and you are trying access 99th

Comment: What makes you think no loop goes outside its range? In `getTilesRemaining`, have you done a `System.out.println(charPool.length)`? I'll bet you that if you did, its value would less than 99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code changed the value of charPool, makes it shorter than 102.

```
String stringPool = new String(onePoint)+ new String(twoPoint)+ new String(threePoint)+ new String(fourPoint)+ new String(fivePoint)+ new String(eightPoint)+ new String(tenPoint)
```

And then you have this line:

```
charPool = stringPool.toCharArray();
```

I believe the length of stringPool is 99 characters, not 102. So when you iterate your charPool with a for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<102; i++){
```

It will "outofindex". You may want to change the above loop to:

```
for(int i=0; i<charPool.length; i++){
```

Comment: 101 characters but all the others is fine.

Comment: I think there are 99 characters, since he didn't add zeroPoint into stringPool.

Comment: Thank you! I think the biggest fault of that was that I used a direct 102 instead of charPool.length; it's just really bad coding practice in general. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome! :) Just keep in mind later that the upper bound of an array may changed if you changed its elements. And it's really important to check the length of an array before iterating on it.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
charPool = stringPool.toCharArray();
```

you create a new array `char[]` which might have a length smaller then 102. Change your loop condition to

```
for(int i=0; i < charPool.length; i++){
```

to process elements in the valid range.

Answer (score 1):

`charPool = stringPool.toCharArray()` will replace the array you allocated with a new one that's apparently only got 98 characters in it.

If your goal is to copy the characters of a string into another character array, use arrayCopy.

Answer (score 0):

The getTiles() method give a string of random tiles, the number of tile depends on the numbersOfTiles. But in the charPool, when you used one char,the char will be replaced with '0',you will not use it again.

The poolReset() method, you reset all chars, all '0' will be replaced by original chars.

The getTilesRemaing() method, you start the loop from 0 index, but the  charPool's length is only 99, so you should end with 99 instead of 102.
And it is very bad idea to use magic number for loop. As friend mentioned above, you'd better to use charPool.length. You can keep the exception away in this way. This function give you the number of tiles. If you mean letters are the tiles, you should change: charPool[i]=='0' to charPool[i]!='0' or return charPool.length - tilesRemaing.

The isEmpty() ,method, it has the same problem with getTilesRemaing().
you can never reach the index 102.

And IDE's Debugger button is always your best friend!

Answer (score 0):

The charPool member isn't being initialized as you think.

```
public Pool(){
  System.out.println("before: " + charPool.length);
  charPool = stringPool.toCharArray();
  System.out.println("after: " + charPool.length);
}
```

yields:

```
before: 102
after: 99
```

In short, use the methods (length) available on your datastructures and don't hard-code values (102) repeatedly into your code.